# Is there a way to get PowerShell to tell VS2013 to attach/detach from a process?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering if I could script VS2013 to that it will attach/detach from a process using PowerShell.  Is it possible?  If so, is there a way of querying what processes VS2013 is currently attached to?

I'm attempting to refresh natviz by detaching and reattaching the debugger to the processes that it is already attached to.  This happens automatically in VS2015 when editing and saving the .natviz file from within the VS2015 editor, but doesn't happen in VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two yes/no questions. The answer is yes to both questions.

According to Wikipedia VS extensions are built using a variety of COM interfaces. There is also a managed wrapper, Managed Package Framework (MPF) that can be used.

Given that interoperability assemblies are available for VS extensions (at least in VS2015), then Powershell can access both the COM and MPF interfaces. (Also remember that Powershell can also create assemblies on the fly using System.Reflection.Emit, so PS can cover a lot of ground).

It might not be easy, but it could be done.

BTW, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.debuggedprocesses.aspx) is a page that documents a property that gives list of processes currently being debugged.

Comment: I guess my question was wrong.  How do I do this?  I'm not sure how I would go about even accessing the COM API.

Comment: I've never done it myself. I'd recommend finding an example of a VS extension for VS2013. In particular you'd want to look for an example that is related to debugging. However before you do that I recommend you read the part of MSDN near the link in the answer to convince yourself that there is a method(s) that can do what you want.